# Android SDK location in Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, android-studio, sdk

I tried doing several answers for this question, but found out that the answers are not compatible for the latest Android Studio and Ubuntu 18.04.1.

My doubt is that *Which directory I have to select* for as Android SDK location?

[image]

**Background:** I Installed Android Studio from software center. It was shown **Android SDK tool is missing** at final step of installation. I ignored it and finished installation and proceeded till this step.

Comment: I am trying from 3 days, but got no all-in-one solution over internet.

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu 18, check this is the path: `/home/{your user name}/Android/Sdk`

To set your path use this command below:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/{your user name}/Android/Sdk

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```